# googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to build a distribution app, I'm using googlemaps module and want to make a distance Matrix to calculate the closest destinations from a stable point on the map.
I'm using `gmaps.distance_matrix` but after the 3 loops I'm getting the title error.

From other stackover articles already I tried use `time.sleep()` but doesn't seems working!

The first 3 results are fine but after I get an error!
If I'm not explaining something fine, let me know please!

```
import xlrd
import googlemaps
import collections
import time

loc=r'C:\Users\spyro\Desktop\files\Hotels.xlsx'
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
names=[]
address=[]
info={}
for i in range(sheet.ncols):
    if (sheet.cell_value(0,i)=="Name")  :
        for k in range(sheet.nrows):
            names.append(sheet.cell_value(k,i))
    if (sheet.cell_value(0,i)=="Address"):
        for k in range(sheet.nrows):
            address.append(sheet.cell_value(k,i))
for n,a in zip(names,address):
    info[n]=a
gmaps= googlemaps.Client(key="My key")
address="1062 Budapest, Andrássy út 53."
distances=collections.deque()

for i,n in info.items():
try:
    print(n)
    dist=gmaps.distance_matrix(address,n)["rows"][0]["elements"][0]
except Exception as e:
    time.sleep(10)
    dist=gmaps.distance_matrix(address,n)["rows"][0]["elements"][0]
```

Comment: Please please please remove your API key!

Comment: Oh didn't notice it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly the Problem was in .xlsx one of the rows was blank!